# Why don't PHP's MySQL libraries associate affected_rows with the query result object?

Tags: php, mysqli

This is a pretty straightforward question I think, but I'll explain my thinking:

Unless I'm mistaken, the number of affected rows is always inherently linked to a query that has been performed. Similarly, the number of rows returned by a SELECT are inherently linked to that query, and the value is retrieved as such:

```
echo $mysql_result_object->num_rows;
```

Why is it that to retrieve the affected rows from something like an UPDATE or DELETE statement, one should access the value through the connection object?

```
echo $mysql_connection_object->affected_rows;
```

It doesn't seem very logical to me.

Is it simply because query functions (for example `mysqli_query`) return boolean true for INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE statements? In which case... shouldn't they return an empty result object?

Comment: I've re-tagged this from MYSQL to MYSQLi. num_rows and affected_rows are from MYSQLi while mysql_num_rows and mysql_affected_rows are from MYSQL. Correct me if I'm mistaken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pretty much answered your own questions, so I'm just clarifying really.

`num_rows` operates on the result set.  It is therefore only valid for operations that return a result set. i.e. SELECT or SHOW.

INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE do not return a result set.  To answer your last sentence; they cannot return an empty result set, since they are already returning a boolean.

`affected_rows` will return the number of affected rows for the last query associated with a link_identifier.

So, you cannot use `num_rows` for INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, but you **can** use `affected_rows` for for a SELECT, in which case it operates like `num_rows`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I guess the real question is "Why the inconsistent return types? What's the point?". It strikes me that error information, number of rows returned and number of affected rows could all be encapsulated in an all-purpose mysqli_result object.